# How to use NAnt from C# program

Tags: c#, runtime, wrapper, nant

Looks like all NAnt classes are internal and there's no a public managed API exposed from NAnt. Is there a way I can call NAnt from C# program with a custom script and parameters? Is there any 3rd party wrappers available somewhere?
For now I'm considering two options: spawning a process and modifying NAnt manifest to add InternalsVisibleTo.

Comment: Not sure what your requirement is, but I think using Process.Start could yield a result you want.

Comment: your best bet might be calling your Nant script via a command line call within your C# program.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands). You can do the following.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "NAnt.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "-buildfile:NantScript.build";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```